# Dataframe Comprehension in Pandas Python to create new Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to `Pandas` but would like to create one dataframe from another based on the condition that the name is `Mel`. It looks like my new dataframe is only a pointer the only old one (based on the index number that is printed out).

I'm essentially looking for the equivalent of this:

```
BabyDataSet = [['Bob', 968], ['Jessica', 155], ['Mary', 77], ['John', 578], ['Mel', 973]]
filtered_list = [x for x in BabyDataSet if x[0] == 'Mel']
print filtered_list
df = pd.DataFrame(data=filtered_list, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
print df
```

MyCode:

```
import pandas as pd

BabyDataSet = [['Bob', 968], ['Jessica', 155], ['Mary', 77], ['John', 578], ['Mel', 973]]
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])

#create a new dataframe for Bob
new_df = df.ix[['Mel' in x for x in df['Names']]]
print new_df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to walk the df, just pass a boolean condition to filter the df:

```
In [216]:
new_df = df[df['Names']=='Mel']
new_df

Out[216]:
  Names  Births
4   Mel     973
```

**EDIT**

To reset the index call `reset_index()`, as to whether `new_df` is a reference to the orig df or not, it's not:

```
In [224]:
new_df = df[df['Names']=='Mel']
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
new_df

Out[224]:
   index Names  Births
0      4   Mel     973

In [225]:    
new_df['Names'] = 'asdas'
df

Out[225]:
     Names  Births
0      Bob     968
1  Jessica     155
2     Mary      77
3     John     578
4      Mel     973
```

Comment: The index here is still 4. Does that mean if I change df, new_df will also change? How can I start the index back at 0 for new_df?

Comment: You can call `reset_index()`, see my update, also it won't affect the orig df

Comment: What if I wanted to use contains rather than ==?

Comment: `df[df['Names'].str.contains('Mel')]`